# Assignment in constructor vs direct assignment

Tags: c#

a basic question popped in my head this morning. Here it is:

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object _myField = new object();

    ...
}
```

and doing the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object _myField;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _myField = new object();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to demonstrate [casperOne's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353409/assignment-in-constructor-vs-direct-assignment/3353419#3353419)...

```
using System;

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result for {0}: {1}", GetType(),
                          CalledByConstructor());
    }

    protected abstract string CalledByConstructor();
}

public class VariableInitializer : BaseClass
{
    private string foo = "foo";

    protected override string CalledByConstructor()
    {
        return foo;
    }
}

public class ConstructorInitialization : BaseClass
{
    private string foo;

    public ConstructorInitialization()
    {
        foo = "foo";
    }

    protected override string CalledByConstructor()
    {
        return foo;
    }
}


public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new VariableInitializer();
        new ConstructorInitialization();
    }
}
```

Here the base class constructor calls an abstract method implemented in the child class - this means we get to see the state of the object *before its constructor body starts executing*. The results are here:

```
Result for VariableInitializer: foo
Result for ConstructorInitialization:
```

As you can see, the variable initializer has already executed - but in the case where initialization only occurs in the constructor body, `foo` still has its default value of null.

Calling virtual methods from constructors is generally a *very bad idea* for precisely this sort of reason.

Comment: I am genuinely impressed. This is a fantastic demonstration.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in the first, the field is initialized *before* the constructor call.  In the second, the field is initialized *during* the constructor call.

Comment: Ok so I was a little mistaken, although both will only occur when you attempt construction of an object, semantically they can be very different as you can inline-initialize a variable from a method call, which could incur any raft of logic problems.

Comment: Such an obvious answer but I can't as of yet think of any other difference. *(Morning haze?)*

Comment: @Chaos: Have a look at my answer for a demonstration of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [casperOne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353409/assignment-in-constructor-vs-direct-assignment/3353419#3353419), those are the only two possible approaches to initializing a `readonly` field. [Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx):

> When a field declaration includes a
>   readonly  modifier, assignments to the
>   fields introduced by the declaration
>   can only occur as part of the
>   declaration or in a constructor in the
>   same class.

In contrast, other fields (ie. not marked `readonly`) can be assigned elsewhere in the class, such as via a method call, although that could lead to needing to check its state before usage.